# SimpleHtmlDom + multiple urls + include GET

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom, server-side-includes

I have two pages. list.php and userinfo.php.

list.php **scrapes** a list of users from another website and gets three strings: $id, $nick and $level, while the other one, userinfo.php?id=id, uses the id to **scrape** from user profile, getting three strings: $gold, $hp and $guild.

They work properly separated, but I want to use $id from list.php as the $id for userinfo.php.
I tried using
`include("userinfo.php?".$id."");` in list.php, but it didn't work, so I tried `include("userinfo.php");` and put an if in userinfo.php to check if there is any functional $id before cheking if there is an functional $_GET["id"].

What I want is to use $id in the url being scraped by userinfo.php for each user found by list.php and then show a list with $id, $level and $nick from list.php and $gold, $hp and $guild from userinfo.php

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659323/making-a-get-request-to-another-php-file-in-php

Comment: Thank you! I found out the problem. The pages were both requiring the plugin, causing it to try to redeclare the same function, so I kept receicing an error.